# chkrootkit awk not found

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, awk, rootkit

I am using chkrootkit 0.53 on my ubuntu dekstop 18.04

When I was doing scan with `

> ./chkrootkit -p /folder

it give me error

`chkrootkit: can't find 'awk' .`

Could anyone help?
Thank you

Comment: If the `awk` command is not installed you need to install it.

Comment: Checked awk is already installed, even I install gawk nothing change